# I don't apply setFrame:CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

```
[Button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 0)];
[Button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 0)];
[Button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 0)];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Button1];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Button2];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Button3];
```

I want to add button in the NavigationBar. NavigationBar have 3 buttons.

Navigation Composition like this.

```
button 1  button 2          text          button3
```

But I didn't show that. this like.

```
          button 2          text          button3
```

Button1, Button2 and Button3 are an Image.

I thought that Button1 setFrame didn't work.

I think setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,0) works Button1 and setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,0) works Button2. so, Button1 is erased by Button2 setFrame.

How to work this Button1 setFrame ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `setFrame:` calls. You cannot assign two buttons to `leftBarButtonItem`. The second assignment overwrites the first. You should create a blank view, add the two buttons to this view (setting their frames correctly so that they are located side by side), and then create a bar button item with this container view.

Comment: Also note that you're leaking all three UIBarButtonItems. You need to release or autorelease these after assigning them to the buttonItem properties.